# adding data in firebase firestore React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have `singUp` function. I successfuly create a new user in Authentication section. After that I can even get his uid. But I have no idea why setting a new document in collection `user` function doesn't work. Like it would be never start.. Even `.then()` or `.catch()` methods doesn't show their `console.log()`. I am using almost the same code in another project and everything is fine there.

```
export const signUp = (newUser) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        firebase.firestore().collection('users').where('nick', '==', newUser.nick).get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                if (snapshot.empty) {
                    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                        newUser.email,
                        newUser.password
                    ).then((resp) => {
                        console.log(resp)
                        console.log(resp.user.uid)

                        firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(resp.user.uid).set({
                            name: newUser.name,
                            age: newUser.age
                        }).then(function () {
                            console.log("Document successfully written!");
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
                        });

                    }).then(() => {
                        dispatch({ type: "SIGNUP_SUCCESS" });
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err)
                        let error;
                        if (err.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use')
                            error = 'Adres e-mail jest już w użyciu!'
                        dispatch({ type: "SIGNUP_ERROR", error })
                    })
                } else {
                    let error = 'Ten nick jest już zajęty!'
                    dispatch({ type: "SIGNUP_ERROR", error })
                }
            })

    }
}
```

And my console :
[image]

Comment: It looks like these logs are printed: `console.log(resp)
                        console.log(resp.user.uid)` and this shows up too `dispatch({ type: "SIGNUP_SUCCESS" });`. What **isn't** working?

Comment: Adding user to 'users' collection. Function after `console.log(resp.user.uid)`

Comment: you forgot to return the promise inside the first `then` of `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean...

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the promise from setting the user's collection as follows:

```
export const signUp = (newUser) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        firebase.firestore().collection('users').where('nick', '==', newUser.nick).get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                if (snapshot.empty) {
                    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                        newUser.email,
                        newUser.password
                    ).then((resp) => {
                        console.log(resp)
                        console.log(resp.user.uid)

                        // ******* add the return statement here *******
                        return firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(resp.user.uid).set({
                            name: newUser.name,
                            age: newUser.age
                        }).then(function () {
                            console.log("Document successfully written!");
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
                        });

                    }).then(() => {
                        dispatch({ type: "SIGNUP_SUCCESS" });
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err)
                        let error;
                        if (err.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use')
                            error = 'Adres e-mail jest już w użyciu!'
                        dispatch({ type: "SIGNUP_ERROR", error })
                    })
                } else {
                    let error = 'Ten nick jest już zajęty!'
                    dispatch({ type: "SIGNUP_ERROR", error })
                }
            })

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I just saw what did you mean. But it  didn't help, now my function just stopped. Even ` dispatch({ type: "SIGNUP_SUCCESS" });` doesn't work now.

Comment: It looks like I can read data from database, but I can't write new documents...

Comment: @poldeeek what does your security rules look like?

Comment: I created it in test mode and didn't touch them : `match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 7, 6);
    }`

Comment: @poldeeek Your security rules looks fine. Can you post the error logs?

Comment: I could but there is not any errors. Console looks like in my ask. With adding return in .then() the only change is that signup_success doesn't show.

Comment: Should there also be a `return` in front of `firebase.firestore().collection('users')...`?

Comment: When I remove `firebase.firestore().collection('user').where('nick', '==', newUser.nick).get()
            .then(snapshot => {` then it works. But I don't why... In another project this is fine with this. Also I need to check if nick is already taken and I don't know how could I check this in different way..